# PHP Insert into database not working

Tags: php, mysql

Greetings I made the following php script so that I could edit text and it would save to a db for future use. However I'm hitting a slight snag at the  update / insert queries. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but only one of the commands will execute. I'm not sure if this is a hosting issue or am I doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

```
if (isset($_SESSION["logged"]) && $_SESSION["logged"]==1){  
    if ($_POST['action']=="edit"){
        $query=mysql_query("select * from page where active=1 AND heading='".$_POST['selectedpage']."'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        echo "<h1>HTML Editor </h1><br>";
        echo "<form name='saveform' action='./action.php'  method='post'>";
        echo "<textarea rows='100' cols='100' name='updateBox'>".$row['content']."</textarea>";
        echo "<br><input name='action' type='submit' value='save edit'>";
        echo "<input name='heading' type='hidden' value='".$row['heading']."'>";
        echo "</form>";
    } else if($_POST['action']=="save edit"){
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE page SET active='0' where heading='".$_POST['heading']."'");
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT into page(heading,content,active) values('".$_POST['heading']."','".$_POST['updateBox']."','1')");
        echo "<p>Changes saved succesfully!</p>";
        echo "$_POST['updateBox']";
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have some syntax errors on the last two lines.

Comment: I'm tired of seeing these types of questions on SO.  It makes the PHP community look bad.  Create your own Development Environment with Wampserver or XAMMP and test the code!

Comment: Which of the commands works and which doesn't? Also, you have some major SQL injection flaws here. Never insert data straight from user supplied input (POST, GET, COOKIE, etc.) without using mysql_real_escape_string on it first, or using a prepared statement.

Comment: Offhand, I'm guessing you typed in an apostrophe into the textarea - since you don't escape special characters in your insert query, an apostrophe will terminate the string in the query, causing a syntax error.

Comment: @Yada - seriously!  If everyone could just be an expert PHP developer, we wouldn't need to have **ANY** PHP questions!  We should shut down the site to everyone who doesn't have 20 years of development experience!

Comment: @Yada, this worked fine on my localmachine. Thats why I asked if it was a hosting issue.

Comment: @Yada - I don't think it makes the community look bad at all. It shows that there are people out there still learning, still keen to improve their knowledge and doing the right thing - turning to people who know better for advice. One persons simple question is another persons most difficult. For all you know this chap has been banging his head in his test environment for half an hour and he's turned to the SO community for assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call `echo mysql_error($query)` after each query you run, you will be able to see if there is an error with that query.  There could be a problem with your query content.

You are not performing any sanitizing for SQL injection, so if your content has a quotation mark in it, it will break your query.  This is fairly dangerous (your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection from user input), and you should consider using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on all your query variables, or switching to the [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/MySQLi) drivers.  These drivers support query binding, which is an excellent method to prevent SQL injection.

**Edit for editorialism  :)**

As an aside, it's generally pretty easy to come up with a quick database wrapper or function handler to handle these kind of errors for you automatically.  I use a class-based wrapper, but if you didn't want to go that far just now, you could do something like this:

```
//very quick-and-dirty
function queryOrDie($query)
{
    $query = mysql_query($query);
    if (! $query) exit(mysql_error());
    return $query;
}
```

You could just pass all your queries through that, and you'd have an easier time of debugging it.  There are a lot of database wrapper classes out there too, I'd highly recommend you take a poke around.  They make life much easier.  :)

Answer (score 3):

What's the error?

At the start of the script add this PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also try this:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT into page(heading,content,active) values('".$_POST['heading']."','".$_POST['updateBox']."',1)");
```

Also :) using data from the POST directly in the insert query is a security threat:
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: PHP's error reporting functions and settings have no effect on database errors, which are reported through specific functionality in the MySQL (et. al) module.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `heading` is not defined as key or unique. This may cause a problem in your context.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the PHP (INSERT INTO) query not working:
my original query was:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `videousers` (`user_id`,`user_name`,`user_password`,`contact_person`,`organisation`,`contact_tel`,`email`) VALUES ('','{$user}','{$pass}','{$cperson}','{$organ}','{$cphone}','{$email}'");
```

it was not working, so I have changed to the following query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT videousers SET user_name='$user',user_password='$pass', contact_person='$cperson', organisation='$organ', contact_tel='cphone', email='$email'");
```

and it worked. I don't know why, but since it works, I use this to finish my work.

Comment: You could see what the issue with the first statement was if you looked at mysql_error. In your second statement, you're not trying to add anything into user_id - I suspect that that's the problem.